# How to use random port for JUNIT Testcases using Spring Boot 1.4.0 +

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit4, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am using spring boot 1.3.6 and my JUNIT Test cases are running fine, after upgrading to spring boot 1.4.0 and attempting to remove deprecated classes is throwing me error

**My JUNITCLASS with 1.3.x**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})
public class CustomerControllerIT {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;
    private URL base;
    private RestTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private DataBuilder dataBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private static final String JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"; 


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.base = new URL("http://localhost:" + port + "/rest/customers");
        template = new TestRestTemplate();      

        /* remove and reload test data */
        customerRepository.deleteAll();     
        dataBuilder.createCustomers().forEach(customer -> customerRepository.save(customer));       
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllCustomers() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity(base.toString(), String.class);     
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));

        List<Customer> customers = convertJsonToCustomers(response.getBody());      
        assertThat(customers.size(), equalTo(3));       
    }

private List<Customer> convertJsonToCustomers(String json) throws Exception        {        
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(json, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Customer.class));
}
}
```

**MyClass with 1.4.0**

Updates done

- Removed deprecated TestRestTemplate with spring suggested one
- Running with SpringRunner instead of SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
- Replaced @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class) with @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class , webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

After Changes

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class , webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CustomerControllerIT {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;
    private URL base;
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private DataBuilder dataBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private static final String JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"; 


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.base = new URL("http://localhost:" + port + "/rest/customers");
        template = new TestRestTemplate();      

        /* remove and reload test data */
        customerRepository.deleteAll();     
        dataBuilder.createCustomers().forEach(customer -> customerRepository.save(customer));       
    }
}
```

Now I am receiving NPE when i try to run JUNIT Testcase, How can I set the random port to make my JUNIT test case running in Spring Boot 1.4.0 +?

**Update :**

Here is the stacktrace of the issue

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.socket.MockServerContainerContextCustomizer.customizeContext(MockServerContainerContextCustomizer.java:38)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of the NPE and why have you commented out the `@Value` annotation on the `port` field?

Comment: Hi Wilkinson, I have attached the stacktrace of the Issue and While testing I tried by keeping port value as is and by commenting out while pasting in stackoverflow forgot to remove it. So it can be ignored . Attached error is when I didn't commented my @Value on the port field

Comment: could you please post your Application.java, just in case there is something unexpected in it, like ".web(false);"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) I have updated your latest sample.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CustomerControllerIT {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private DataBuilder dataBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private static final String JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"; 


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        /* remove and reload test data */
        customerRepository.deleteAll();     
        dataBuilder.createCustomers().forEach(customer -> customerRepository.save(customer));       
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllCustomers() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("/rest/customers", String.class);     
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));

        List<Customer> customers = convertJsonToCustomers(response.getBody());      
        assertThat(customers.size(), equalTo(3));       
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you removed @WebAppConfiguration? I tried, it works!

Comment: I also updated the TestRestTemplate to be autowired and removed it's base_url setup. That stuff is automatically dealt with for you so you can clean up the test to not care about the host:port and instead just use relative URL's on the template.

Answer (score 1):

for JUNIT 5 the solution that worked for me is the bellow (taken from [Spring's documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HttpRequestTest {

    @Value(value="${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void greetingShouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/",
                String.class)).contains("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

The interesting points are:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

For the bellow there is no need for further configuration in application.properties for example. It works as is:

```
@Value(value="${local.server.port}")
private int port;
```

Then you autowire the testRestTemplate and **include** the baseUrl in the call to your endpoint.